# Colocar símbolo (%) no round em R

Tags: r

Como posso colocar o símbolo % dentro do round?

Ex.:

```
x = 75.35485

valor <- round(x,2)
valor
> 75.35
```

A dúvida é como inserir o % como texto dentro do round para que a minha saída seja:

```
> 75.35 %
```

Comment: Seja benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português! A forma mais simples, transformando a classe para string `paste(round(x,2), "%")` .

Answer (score 1):

Podes utilizar a função `paste()` do Rbase:

```
x = 75.35485

valor <- paste(round(x,2), "%", sep = " ")

valor

[1] "75.35 %"
```

Answer (score 0):

Eis duas maneiras.

```r
x = 75.35485

paste0(round(x, 2), "%")
#> [1] "75.35%"

scales::percent(x/100, accuracy = 0.01)
#> [1] "75.35%"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>